# dojo validation textbox error display

Tags: validation, textbox, dojo

I have dojo Vaslidation textbox with required set to "true". But when I hit the submit button and submit the form,the form is prevented from submitting, but doesnot display error messages either.
But when I click the textbox, it is highlighted to red and show the message. 
My requirement is, When i click on submit without entering data or invalid data, it should display the error message without having to click the input field.
How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an event (`dojo/on`) to listen for the form submit and return true/false. See example here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/form/Form.html#validate